No available storage method found" error when implementing custom storage driver
Description
I'm trying to implement a custom storage driver for JupyterLite to interface with a Rails backend. However, I'm encountering a "No available storage method found" error when attempting to use this custom driver.
Steps to Reproduce

Created a custom storage driver implementing the Contents.IDrive interface
Registered the custom driver with JupyterLite
Configured jupyter-lite.json to use the custom driver
Loaded JupyterLite in the browser

Expected Behavior
JupyterLite should recognize and use the custom storage driver for content management.
Actual Behavior
JupyterLite throws a "No available storage method found" error and fails to initialize properly.
Configuration
Here's my jupyter-lite.json configuration:
  "jupyter-config-data": {
     "appPlugins": [
          { "id": "rails-storage-plugin", "url": "./plugins/custom-storage-driver.js" }
        ],
     "contentsStorageDrivers": ["customStorage"],
     "contentsStorageName": "customStorage",
  }

JupyterLite should recognize and use the custom storage driver for content management.
i am trying to use api to fetch files from my server and use it , i want to use all crud actions
